# Powershell CTRL+F Highlighting Color

Tags: powershell

I like to use a darker background but I cant find the setting to changer the highlighting. Every time I use it its like I'm finding waldo and it defeats the purpose.

Example:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA0c9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the ISE? The command window just inverts the colours so anything other than medium grey is easy to find.

Anyway this is a really unfortunate feature of Windows, the highlight text isn't controlled by the ISE but by Personalisation settings. Go into Control Panel, Personalisation, Window Colour, then "Advanced Appearance Settings..." and you'll get the old options to change window colours.

The "Selected Items" setting will change the colour of highlighted text EVERYWHERE IN WINDOWS. So if you decide to go down this route you're going to need to pick a colour you can easily find on both your ISE and the standard black-on-white theme. I recommend a slightly lighter blue.

Answer (score 0):

Two Windows registry keys control this highlighting of search results in PowerShell ISE.
The one for Ctrl+F uses "GrayText" as base. Default is "109 109 109", and "192 192 192" makes it easier to spot with the dark theme.
The second one is "Hilight", which is the color used when you close the "Search" box. Default is "0 120 215", whereas "107 166 214" works better.
They both are applied with an opacity of 40% (calculated guess from screenshots), you end up with less bright colors in PS-ISE than you might expect. Since Windows got, by endless Microsoft wisdom, the actual color panel we had since Windows 95 removed, you have to use this way.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors]
"GrayText"="192 192 192"
"Hilight"="107 166 214"
```

Result while "Search" is active:

[image: Search result highlight with "GrayText"="192 192 192"]

Result when the editing window is active:

[image: Marked result highlight with "Hilight"="107 166 214"]

Colors with more brightness have negative usability effects on other windows applications, but you are free to go further of course.

Just for comparison: The is what "Search" it looks like before changing it:

[image: Search result highlight with "GrayText"="109 109 109"]