# Any way to change the highlight color of Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

[image]
This highlight color in PS ISE is really annoying, I can only use the light theme to avoid it. The built-in theme editor seems lack of option pointing to this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell CTRL+F Highlighting Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343440/powershell-ctrlf-highlighting-color)

Comment: @Paxz No, I can't find the settings mentioned in that answer anywhere. I'm using Win10.

Comment: I've just added the answer to [Powershell CTRL+F Highlighting Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343440/powershell-ctrlf-highlighting-color) , which might work for you too.